# ClassCast error when using org.springframework.messaging.Message with Protobuf object as kafka message

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, spring-kafka

I am using `spring-kafka` with producer property as below

> ```
> key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
> value-serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer
> ```

and my code looks something like this -

```
                         Message<Event> message = MessageBuilder
                        .withPayload(protobufStruct)
                        .setHeader(MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP, Instant.now().toString())
                        .build();

                kafkaTemplate.send(topic, new MessageKey(key).toString(), message);
```

When producing the message, I am getting an error like

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage cannot be cast to
> class com.google.protobuf.Message
> (org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage and
> com.google.protobuf.Message are in unnamed module of loader 'app')    at
> io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer.serialize(KafkaProtobufSerializer.java:34)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1015)

What is the mistake that I am doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no overloaded `send(topic, key, Message<?>)` method.

`send(topic, K, V)` is being used so you are sending the `GenericMessage` as the payload (`record.value()`).

Use `kafkaTemplate.send(topic, new MessageKey(key).toString(), protobufStruct);` instead.

If you want to set the timestamp yourself, use the `send(ProducerRecord<K, V>)` variant.

Comment: I have few more header information which I want to send with my message. What should I do in that case?

Comment: You can either add them to the `ProducerRecord` or use the `send(Message<?>)` variant - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#sending-messages `>When you use the methods with a Message<?> parameter, the topic, partition, and key information is provided in a message header that includes the following items:

KafkaHeaders.TOPIC

KafkaHeaders.PARTITION

KafkaHeaders.KEY

KafkaHeaders.TIMESTAMP`